# Undefined Variable: Not displaying data

Tags: php

Basically trying to filter out records from an ID sent via POST.

Below is the function I am running.

```
 function displayinvoice($supid){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM companies WHERE compID = " . $supid);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
    return $row;
```

This is the on the page code

```
include '../inc/functions-jams.php';

$dropid = $_POST['cmyid'];

displayinvoice($dropid);
```

And I have this in the body of the doc

```
<? echo $row['compName'];?>
```

Now $dropid is picking up as I have echoed it out on the page but the body code is returning this error.

Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\yourwedding\backend\sup-invoices-02.php on line 59

Been at it for a few hours now and getting nowhere. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection. Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app. http://bobby-tables.com/php.html has examples to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the returned value:

```
$row = displayinvoice($dropid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok aside from the SQL Injection issues...

Try

```
$row = displayinvoice($dropid);

<? echo $row['compName'];?>
```

Comment: Hi Liam, Thanks your right didn't add the function to a variable. Basic stuff I know but only been at this a few weeks on and off. Anyway that did it thanks.

Comment: No need to apologise, we've all been there. Glad it's fixed.